# How should one interpret $R[A_1,..,A_n]$ where $R$ is a unital ring and $A_i\in M_{n\times n}(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, finitely-generated

How should one interpret $R[A_1,..,A_n]$ where $R$ is a unital ring and $A_i\in M_{n\times n}(R)$?

Intuitively, I considered $R[A_1,..,A_n]$ as almost a set of polynomials where '$X_i$' is each '$A_i$' and the coefficient comes from $R$. (So almost like a multivariable polynomial)

However, the definition I was given was *"the unital subring that is generated by **scalar multiples of the identity matrix** and $A_1$,...,$A_n$."* This almost coincides with what I initially thought, except, the bold text is what confuses me.

I would just think it is *"the unital subring that is generated by **the identity matrix** and $A_1$,...,$A_n$."* Is the 'scalar multiples' part of the definition necessary? If so why is it necessary?

Comment: You want to be able to multiply by elements of $R$, so you include all $rI$ for $r\in R$ and $I$ the identity matrix. Otherwise you will get the smaller subring corresponding to (the image of) $\mathbb Z$ in $R$.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Maybe I should double-check my understanding on finitely generated subrings. Say if we consider the subring generated by ${I, A_1,...A_n}$, is it basically the set of matrices that can be obtained from a finite amount of steps of multiplying and adding elements of ${I, A_1,...A_n}$?

Comment: Yes, so you will never get something like $rA_i$ with $r\in R$ (unless $r$ lies in the image of $\mathbb Z\to R$).